# Use admob account of terminated google play accounts with new google play account?

Tags: android, admob

Can I use Ad Mob Account Which Is Verified And used For Google Play Developer Account

But Now My Google Account Is Terminated Due to Some **Violation,**

So Can I use This Ad Mob Account For New Google Play Developer Account?

Comment: What was the violation? Because if you violated G.Play Terms, then it's most likely that you violated admobs as well, and your account will also be terminated in a matter of days/weeks.

Comment: REASON FOR TERMINATION: Prior violations of the Content Policy and Developer Distribution Agreement by this or associated accounts as outlined in previous emails sent to the registered email address(es) of the Publisher account(s).

Answer (score 0):

You can use your same Admob account in different Google Play Developer accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use, i have also a suspended account i use same Admob account for another GP account.

Comment: If one of your admob account get terminate for current Google Play store account then can we use other amdob account like say my friend admob account?

Comment: Yes You Can But For Security Reason Don't Use That PC Also Don't Use Chrome